# how to use scanf unsigned int

Tags: c, scanf

I have the following

```
 unsigned int value = 12;
 int res = std::sscanf("-567", "%u", &value);
```

When this is run res is 1 indicating 1 match and value is set to 4294966729
Whereas I was expecting no matches to be made

I would be grateful if someone could explain this behaviour.

Comment: `std::sscanf` does not very much look like `C` to me.

Comment: How do you expect `-567` to be represented as an *unsigned* value?

Comment: @stackptr `snscanf` has *nothing* to do with avoiding overflows.

Comment: @rustyx Sorry, got confused with `snprintf`

Comment: @stackptr `snprintf` has nothing to do with avoiding overflows :)

Comment: @AlterMann What do you mean? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/ "If the resulting string would be longer than n-1 characters, the remaining characters are discarded and not stored, but counted for the value returned by the function."

Comment: @stackptr, restricts the __number of bytes to store__, not the maximum value assigned to a parameter

Answer (score 8):

The [C11 Standard states](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p12)

*"... whose format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of the `strtoul` function with the value 10 for the base argument ..."*

and, [for `strtoul`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.1.4p5)

*"... If the subject sequence begins with a minus sign, the value resulting from the conversion is negated ..."*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned int value;
    int res;

    res = sscanf("-567", "%u", &value);
    if (res == 1) {
        printf("Value: %u\n", value);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
    }

    res = sscanf("567", "%u", &value);
    if (res == 1) {
        value = ~value + 1; // add 1 in two's complement machines
        printf("Value: %u\n", value);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Who would have thought that `strtoul` is *specified* to happily eat negative integers?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior happens because every negative integer has a corresponding unsigned value, allowing `sscanf` to parse negative values for an `unsigned int`. If you want to ensure that `sscanf` matched a positive integer, you have to parse the string as decimal integer (`"%d"`) and use an `if` statement:

```cpp
long int value:
unsigned int value_ui;
scanf("%ld", &value);

if (value < 0)
    printf("error");
else
    value_ui = (unsigned int) value;
```

Comment: `if(value<0)` when `value` is declared as `unsigned int` is always false, isn't it?

Comment: @AlterMann when i wrote value i meant is the input int type and not the unsigned int

Comment: Ok, then you should declare `value` as `long int` to be in the range `0 - UINT_MAX` (overflow of `signed int` is undefined behaviour)

Answer (score 1):

Given your usage of `std::sscanf()`, you're actually using C++, not C.   But C++'s `sscanf()` behaves in largely the same way as in C.

The specification of the `%u` format specifier allows a sign to be included.   Which would essentially mean modulo arithmetic will be employed.   Assuming a 32 `unsigned int` type, the result will be modulo `4294967296` to produce a value between `0` and `4294967295`.   `-567` modulo `4294967296` (aka the smallest positive remainder obtained on dividing `-567` by `4294967296`) is `4294966729`.

Answer (score 0):

If you go through the docs of `sscanf` function you will find that return type of `sscanf` is the number of variables filled which is essentially one in this case i.e. the variable `value`. Also `value` is showing a very large number because you are storing a negative integer in it and displaying it in unsigned integer format. This will lead to modulo arithmetic and final result will be (-567)%(**max unsigned integer value**). To put it in simple words, it would be two's complement of 567. If instead you had used %d format specifier for `value` it would have shown -567 only. For more details on `sscanf` usage refer following link:

For C:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm

For C++:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/